Elysia/Eden Treaty types error,
import {  redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit";
import { OAuth2Client } from "google-auth-library";
import { getUserInfo } from "../../http";
import 'dotenv/config';
import { treaty } from "@elysiajs/eden";
import { type AUTHORIZATION } from "../../../../backend/src/routes/authorization"
export const GET = async ({ url }: { url: URL }) => {
const code = await url.searchParams.get("code");
try {
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
process.env.PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
process.env.PUBLIC_CLIENT_SECRET,
process.env.PUBLIC_GOOGLE_REDIRECT
);
if (!code) return;
const response = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
oAuth2Client.setCredentials(response.tokens);
const user = oAuth2Client.credentials;

const userInfoResponse = await getUserInfo(user.access_token);
if (!userInfoResponse.success) return


const app = treaty<AUTHORIZATION>('http://localhost:3000')

const addAdmin = await app.api.admin.add.post({email: "zsombinagy.14@gmail.com"})

const responseCheckAdmin = await app.api.admin.login.post(userInfoResponse.data)

} catch (err) {
console.log("Error logging in with Google", err);
}
throw redirect(303, "/signup");
};
I'm using Elysia from Backenden, but using sveltekit, for some reason in "treaty" the type is underlined and it says Type 'Elysia<"", false, { decorator: {}; store: {}; derive: {}; resolve: {}; }, { type: {}; error: {}; }, { schema: {}; macro: {}; }, { api: { admin: { add: { post: { body: { email: string; }; params: Record<never, string>; query: unknown; headers: unknown; response: { ...; }; }; }; }; }; } & { ...; }, { ...; }, { ...; }>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Elysia<any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any>'.
Types have separate declarations of a private property 'dependencies'.

Downgrading @elysiajs/eden to 1.0.14 helped me. The latest release may be corrupted.
https://github.com/elysiajs/eden/actions/runs/9611256126
package.json:
...
"@elysiajs/eden": "1.0.14"
...


I think this should work:
import { redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit";
import { OAuth2Client } from "google-auth-library";
import { getUserInfo } from "../../http";
import 'dotenv/config';
import { treaty, type TreatyInstance } from "@elysiajs/eden";
import type { AUTHORIZATION } from "../../../../backend/src/routes/authorization";

export const GET = async ({ url }: { url: URL }) => {
    const code = url.searchParams.get("code");
    if (!code) return;

    try {
        const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
            process.env.PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            process.env.PUBLIC_CLIENT_SECRET,
            process.env.PUBLIC_GOOGLE_REDIRECT
        );

        const response = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(response.tokens);

        const userInfoResponse = await getUserInfo(oAuth2Client.credentials.access_token);
        if (!userInfoResponse.success) return;

        const app = treaty<AUTHORIZATION>('http://localhost:3000') as unknown as TreatyInstance<AUTHORIZATION>;

        await app.api.admin.add.post({ email: "zsombinagy.14@gmail.com" });
        await app.api.admin.login.post(userInfoResponse.data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error logging in with Google", err);
    }

    throw redirect(303, "/signup");
};

This ensures compatibility with your AUTHORIZATION type. Make sure your type definitions and environment variables are correctly configured.

Unfortunately it doesn't help the situation, and also underlines TratyInstance: Module '"@elysiajs/eden"' has no exported member 'TreatyInstance'

I think the issue has to be from the environment configuration.

The problem is, I'm a beginner programmer using elysia for the first time, but I don't know exactly where to look for the error, what would you say?

Maybe try this out: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/6384/12289
